# Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) upgrading from 0.60.5 to 0.63.3

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

[image]

I am facing issues in upgrading from `0.60.5 to  0.63.3` version. the app is stuck and not running.  Error is

> Invariant Violation: Native modules cannot be null.
>
> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable
> module (calling run application).

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
remove app from the emulator 
npm cache clean --force 
watchman watch-del-all 
cd ios
pod update / pod install
cd ..
npx react-native run-ios
```

thats work for me